# How to load children and parent relation in a model as append attributes inlaravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have Company model with the following columns :
id,
parent_id (used for branches ),
company_name,
mobile_num
I want to get the company children (branches) and parent (main branch) automatically every time I used Company model in Controller
my Code :

```
class Company extends Model 
{
 public $table = 'companies';

    protected $appends = [
        'main_branch',
        'all_branches',
    ];

  public function branches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Company ::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }


    public function main_branch()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id')/*->with(['approvedBranches'])*/;
    }
}

public function getMainBranchAttribute(){ 
        return $this->main_branch()->first();
    }

    public function getAllBranchesAttribute(){ 
        return $this->branches()->get();
    }
```

Now the problem is when I try to get branches I got The following error :

```
"message": "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
"file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\compaines\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOStatement.php",
"line": 199,
"trace": []
```

How can I fix this and get all this attribute auto when I want to get model data
in Controller

Comment: need increase max_execution_time in php.ini file. Because you have much data in your Company table

Comment: IS that will affect in performance and speed ?
If there another best solution please tell me .
Thanks